# How to load SSIS package for any specific date

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a ssis package which runs daily. This ssis package has couple of execute sql tasks which load data for yesterday's transaction. Ex.

```
INSERT INTO Shipped 
(Div_Code, shipment_value, ship_l_id, shipped_qty, shipped_date, whse_code, 
ord_id, ship_id, ship_l_ord_l_id, Created_date)
select ord.DIV_CODE as div_code, ship.SHIPMENT_VALUE as shipment_value, ship_l.SHIP_L_ID as ship_l_id,
ship_l.SHIPPED_QTY as shipped_qty, ship.SHIPPED_DATE as shipped_date, ship.WHSE_CODE as whse_code,
ord.ORD_ID as ord_id, ship.SHIP_ID as ship_id, ship_l.ord_l_id as ship_l_ord_l_id, Getdate() as Created_date
FROM SHIP ship, ORD ord, 
SHIP_L ship_l
WHERE ship.SHIPPED_DATE=(dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))) 
and ship.WHSE_CODE='WPP' and ord.ORD_ID=ship.ORD_ID
and ship.SHIP_ID=ship_l.SHIP_ID
```

All execute sql task has query like above query. and in some query we have date filter which loads data for yesterday. Ex. one query has :

```
ship.SHIPPED_DATE=(dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))). some other query has ord.trans_date=(dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)))
```

this package runs daily through sql server job, so It loads data for yesterday. Now If i want to run for any particular date, How could we achieve from ssis?  I am very new to SSIS. Could anyone guide me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can run your package to change date condition.

```
INSERT INTO Shipped (Div_Code, shipment_value, ship_l_id, shipped_qty, shipped_date, whse_code,

ord_id, ship_id, ship_l_ord_l_id, Created_date) select ord.DIV_CODE as div_code, ship.SHIPMENT_VALUE as shipment_value, ship_l.SHIP_L_ID as ship_l_id, ship_l.SHIPPED_QTY as shipped_qty, ship.SHIPPED_DATE as shipped_date, ship.WHSE_CODE as whse_code, ord.ORD_ID as ord_id, ship.SHIP_ID as ship_id, ship_l.ord_l_id as ship_l_ord_l_id, Getdate() as Created_date from SHIP ship, ORD ord, SHIP_L ship_l where ship.SHIPPED_DATE=(dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))) and ship.WHSE_CODE='WPP' and ord.ORD_ID=ship.ORD_ID and ship.SHIP_ID=ship_l.SHIP_ID
```

change getdate() with your specified date in query and execute package

Comment: Thanks Indra,  
                        But i have 12 execute task like this, So I have to change everywhere. Instead of changing in query, can we achieve throgh parameters in SSIS. Suppose we want to load for may 9th. So can we pass this date as a parameter?

Comment: if you want to pass date parameter as variable then you have to change you sql in package. if you are ready then i will provide code

Comment: Thanks Indra for your reply,
                                             Yes I am ready to change as My package should run daily, but If we want to load data for any specific date, we should be able to load for that specific date also...

Thanks....

Comment: Hi Indra Praksah tiwari,
         Can you guide me how we can achieve this using SSIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See below steps that u can use, it is very simple

1. Create a table with one column with datatype `date`
2. Add one `ExecuteSql` task in your package, write a query to add or
   update with `getdate()`
3. Update your existing SQL query where clause instead of

> WHERE ship.SHIPPED_DATE=(dateadd(day,-1,
>   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)))

Use below one

```
WHERE ship.SHIPPED_DATE=(Select column from tablename)
```

**Logic**: by default your query get `getdate()` from table but if you update your table manually with specific table your package will execute with particular date
We can achieve this with some other way like using environment variable but I think above process will for you.

Comment: Even you can achieve without adding ExecuteSQL task.
just you can create table with one column, add one record with getdate()
change your where clause using table

schedule your package, package will run as per getdate(), becuase table have getdate()
when you run particular date, just you need to update table

Comment: Hi Indra,  
             Thanks for your reply. Here in my package, I have 12 execute sql tasks and each task has same query with different Date filter and some query does not have date filter at all. we have date filter which loads data for yesterday. Ex. one query has ship.SHIPPED_DATE=(dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))). some other query has ord.trans_date=(dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))) and so on. So how it will work?

Thanks